# How do I chain deferred objects in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, asynchronous

Just a small piece of code:

```
return $.when(
  $.get('/url1.json').done(function(r){
    //case 1
  }), $.get('/url2.json').done(function(r) {
    //case 2
  })
).done(function(){return $.get('/url3.json').done(function(r){
  //case 3
})})
```

What this code does:

1. Runs gets for `/url1.json` and `/url2.json` simultainiously and in case of success runs code for `case 1` and `case 2` respectively
2. In case of success of both `/usr1.json` and `url2.json` it runs get for `/url3.json`
3. Returns deferred object (or a promise, nevermind now as I see) which `$.when` returns (so, the object for `/url1.json` and `/url2.json` by `$.when`'s rules)

What I need from it:
1. ...
2. ...
3. Returns deferred object which is returned by `$.get('/url3.json')`

So, maybe I need something like

```
$.when(...).flatMap(function() { return $.get('/url3.json') })
```

Do I have any way of doing it?

Comment: The `flatMap` you're looking for is called **`then`** at [promises](http://promisesaplus.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) instead of `done` to change the promise to the result of the passed in callback.

```
return $.when(
    $.get('/url1.json'), 
    $.get('/url2.json')
  )
  .then(function() {
    return $.get('/url3.json')
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5N9JJ/3/

Comment: Thank you, Jason. Looks like it is exactly what do I need. I checked jquery docs before asking, but didnt understand what the `then` really is...